# How to return void * from thread routine when calling pthread_exit

Tags: c, pthreads

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/join.c

Please see the code in the link above.

Question:

1. The thread routine (`BusyWork`) is supposed to return a `void *` but instead it ends with a call to `pthread_exit()` ( which returns a `void`).

Why is this not flagged as a failure or error? I also do not get any warning.

Comment: The code you linked to will probably give a warning since nothing is returned, but the pointer "returned" from the thread to the second argument in `pthread_join` is the pointer passed as argument to `pthread_exit`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It doesn't give a warning on ubuntu 3.0.0-26-generic-pae

Comment: If you comment out the `pthread_exit` call, you will see a warning (with `-Wall`).  gcc knows that `pthread_exit` does not return to its caller, therefore it doesn't matter that `BusyWork` doesn't return a value.

Comment: And the compiler knows this because when you go look in pthread.h, you will find pthread_exit to be annotated. With gcc, you'd see something like _ _ attribute ( _ _noreturn_ _ ).

Comment: @Zack You said: "gcc knows that pthread_exit does not return to its caller, therefore it doesn't matter that BusyWork doesn't return a value." But why doesn't it matter that the thread routine does not return a void * on exit ? It should return what it promised to return..no?

Comment: @abc It doesn't matter because it never happens.  Note the difference between "this function never returns at all" and "this function returns, but doesn't return a _value_."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing link, taken from `man pthread_create`:

> Upon its creation, the thread executes start_routine, with arg as its sole argument.  If start_routine returns, the effect is as if there was an implicit call to pthread_exit(), using the return value of start_routine as the exit status.

So you have two options (choose one):

- Your routine returns the value and does not call `pthread_exit`
- You pass the return value to `pthread_exit`

As to why it is not flagged: Because the compiler knows `pthread_exit` never returns. How this is accomplished depends on the compiler. On GCC, that can be accomplished using `__attribute__((__noreturn__))`.

Comment: It makes complete sense now.